# How can I mirror a repository from one hosted location to another?

Tags: git

There's a hosted git repository and I don't have write permission for it. I cloned it locally, and would now like to set up my own github version. I basically want to continue hosted development where the other person left off. How can I do establish the remote hosted address as a different location?

Answer (score 1):

Once you have cloned the repository, you probably want to change the **origin** path to your new remote development site, so you would do this:

```
git remote set-url origin https://github.com/your_user/my_new_repo.git
```

or if you prefer SSH then:

```
git remote set-url origin git@github.com:your_user/your_repo.git
```

Now whenever you do `git push` it will push to the repo you pointed origin to.

Answer (score 0):

I am not very clear about your question, sorry that i cannot leave a comment right now...But if what you mean is you want to clone some projects from a read-only repository and push it into your github account, you need to

1. first create a repository in your github account
2. `git remote add somename git://github.com/username/repository.git`
3. `git push somename master`